# convert String to Util date in "dd-MMM-yyyy" fromat

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I am working in Eclipse .
I have string date = "12-DEC-2016"

now i want to convert it into util date in same format. Please help me with this query.

Comment: Have a look at [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html](SimpleDateFormat)

Comment: Like every other answer involing a `String` to `Date` conversion, you start with `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Conversion

To convert a `String` into a `java.util.Date` of a specific format, you can use a `java.text.DateFormat`. `DateFormat` objects can perform conversions in both directions, from `String` to `Date` by calling `format()` and from `Date` to `String` by calling `parse()`. `DateFormat` objects can be obtained in multiple ways, here are some:

- Obtain an instance via one of the `static` `get*Instance()` methods in `DateFormat`. This is especially useful when you want the format to be in the user's locale. For example, `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)`.
- Create your very own specific format by creating an instance of `SimpleDateFormat`. For example, `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")`

You should consider whether you need a particular fixed format or whether you need the format of whatever the user's locale uses. Keep in mind that different countries use different formats.

In case the format is not for a user, but for machine to machine data interchange, you should consider using **ISO 8601** or **RFC 1123** as a format.

Also consider using the `java.time` package instead of `java.util.Date`. The `java.time` package is more powerful in case you need to perform calculations. It usually leads to code which is easier to understand and more precise, especially regarding the handling of time zones, daylight savings, local time vs. UTC and such.

## Notes:

- That you're working in Eclipse doesn't matter to the problem.

## References

- ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
- RFC 1123 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt
- `DateFormat` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html
- `SimpleDateFormat` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
- Java 8 `java.time` package https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [accepted Answer by Hujer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112820/642706) is correct but focuses on the troublesome outmoded classes of java.data.Date/.Calendar & SimpleDateFormat. As suggested, you should be using the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

## `LocalDate`

The new classes include `LocalDate` to represent a date-only value, without time-of-day or time zone.

Parsing requires a `Locale` when your string includes words to be translated, name of day or month. Better to specify explicitly than depend on JVM’s current default Locale.

```
String input = "12-DEC-2016";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d-MM-uuuu" );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```